In Alexa.Cooking.TemperatureController, is it possible to ask for cooktime?
I am developing an Alexa skill for a cooking appliance. The machine requires a cooktime when starting. However, if I activate a temperatureController by Alexa, e.g:

User: Alexa, set machine to roast at 300 degrees.

Alexa will not ask for a cooktime, instead it creating a request with temperatureController.
"directive": {
  ...
  "payload": {
     "targetCookingTemperature": {
       "value": 300,
       "scale": "FAHRENHEIT"
     },
       "cookingMode": {
         "value": "ROAST"
       }
  }
}

I tried disable temperatureController from capabilities in discovery response, however, the skill is not activated at all. e.g:

User: Alexa, set machine to roast at 300 degrees.
Alexa: Machine does not support that.

So I guess to disable temperatureController is not a good idea.
I wonder if it is possible to ask for cooktime when temperatureController is activated. e.g:

User: Alexa, set machine to roast at 300 degrees.
Alexa: For how long?

